# How do you use the BBP Formula to calculate the nth digit of π?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pi

I know what the Bailey-Borweim-Plouffe Formula (BBP Formula)  is—it's $\pi = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{16^k} \left( \frac{4}{8k + 1} - \frac{2}{8k + 4} - \frac{1}{8k + 5} - \frac{1}{8k + 6} \right) \right]$— but how exactly do I use it to calculate a given digit of pi?

Comment: It is still  work; read the original BBP papers and later follow-ups.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_.CF.80  "Though the BBP formula can directly calculate the value of any given digit of π with less computational effort than formulas that must calculate all intervening digits, BBP remains linearithmic whereby successively larger values of n require increasingly more time to calculate; that is, the "further out" a digit is, the longer it takes BBP to calculate it, just like the standard π-computing algorithms."

Comment: @WillJagy
I get that the "farther out" a digit is the more time it takes to calculate it. However, that doesn't really relate to my question. My understanding is that the BBP formula is a digit extraction formula—a formula that can be used to calculate a specific digit of pi _without_ needing to calculate the previous digits. My question is—how exactly do I do that? I don't see how the BBP formula can calculate, say, the 23rd digit of pi.

Comment: I don't know either. Documentation is plentiful.

Comment: @Anonymus If you read French, it's explained in details here http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/articles/Obsession_de_Pi.pdf

Answer (score 7):

The basic idea depends on the following easy result:

The $d+n$-th digit of a real number $\alpha$ is obtained by computing the $n$-th digit of the fractional part of $b^d \alpha$, in base $b$ . (fractional part denoted by $\lbrace \rbrace$.)

For instance:
if you want to find the $13$-th digit of $\pi$ in base $2$, you must calculate the fractional part of $2^{12} \pi$  in base $2$.

$\lbrace2^{12} \pi\rbrace=0.\color{red} 1\color{blue} {111011}..._2$

hence $13$-th digit of $\pi $ is $\color{red} 1$.

$\pi=11.001001000011\color{red} 1\color{blue} {111011010101}..._2$

Now if we want to compute the $n+1$-th hexadecimal digit of $\pi$

we only need to calculate  $\lbrace 16^{n} \pi\rbrace$

you can  do this by using $BBP$ formula

$$\pi = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^k} \left( \frac{4}{8k + 1} - \frac{2}{8k + 4} - \frac{1}{8k + 5} - \frac{1}{8k + 6} \right) $$

$$16^{n} \pi= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{4 \cdot 16^{n-k}}{8k + 1} - \frac{2\cdot 16^{n-k}}{8k + 4} - \frac{ 16^{n-k}}{8k + 5} - \frac{16^{n-k}}{8k + 6} \right)$$

and

$$\lbrace 16^{n} \pi\rbrace=\bigg\lbrace\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}  \left( \frac{4 \cdot 16^{n-k}}{8k + 1} - \frac{2\cdot 16^{n-k}}{8k + 4} - \frac{ 16^{n-k}}{8k + 5} - \frac{16^{n-k}}{8k + 6} \right)\bigg \rbrace$$

Now let $S_j=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^k(8k+1)}$ then

$$\color{blue}{\lbrace 16^{n} \pi\rbrace=\lbrace 4\lbrace 16^{n} S_1\rbrace-2\lbrace 16^{n} S_4\rbrace-\lbrace 16^{n} S_5\rbrace-\lbrace 16^{n} S_6\rbrace \rbrace}$$

using the $S_j$ notation

$$\lbrace 16^{n} S_j\rbrace=\bigg \lbrace \bigg \lbrace\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{16^{n-k}}{8k+j} \bigg \rbrace+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{16^{n-k}}{8k+j}\bigg \rbrace $$

$$=\bigg \lbrace \bigg \lbrace\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{16^{n-k} \mod {8k+j} }{8k+j} \bigg \rbrace+\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{16^{n-k}}{8k+j}\bigg \rbrace$$

Now compute $\lbrace 16^{n} S_j\rbrace$ for $j=1,4,5,6$, combine these four result, then discarding integer parts.

The resulting fraction, when expressed in hexadecimal notation, gives the hex digit of $\pi$ in position $n+1$ .

Comment: What do you mean by "combine these four results" ?

Comment: I don’t understand. In your case, we still need to sum the first $n$ items. The complexity is still $O(n)$, but the constant is reduced?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to calculate the $k$th hex digit, substitute your value for $k$ for everything in the parentheses.

Comment: This is right actually - see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/948400